# Number of rows in a table keeps changing every time I SELECT, can anyone shed light?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I did a import of a bunch of data, and the expected number of rows should have been `41856`.

Now every time I go into the table using `phpMyAdmin`, I see a different amount of rows. There is nothing connecting to it which would change the number of rows.

Here I added a few screen shots of the table, a few seconds apart from each other.

41,610 records, 41,759 records, 41,647 records...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: use `select count(*) from tax_calculation_rate` to get the row count

Comment: When you read FAQ of PHPMyAdmin, you can read, that this isn't exact number of rows... If before number is ~ it's only approximate number of rows.

Comment: More you can read at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138191/phpmyadmin-what-a-tilde-means-in-rows-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138191/phpmyadmin-what-a-tilde-means-in-rows-column)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some storage engines, such as MyISAM and ISAM, store the exact count.
BUT for other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40 to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count."